# Create array according to array output

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array but have no luck.

When I dump my array I get from results, looks ok. I need to create a new array for next processing.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { 
          ["name"]=> string(37) "America , United States , City" 
          ["link"]=> string(48) "https://www.test.com" 
          ["icon"]=> string(50) "  " 
                          } 
         }
```

Based on the array above I need to create array

```
[0]
  ["name"]=>"America",
  [link]=>"https://www.test.com",
  ["icon"]=> string(50) "  "
[1]
  ["name"]=>"United States",
  [link]=>"https://www.test.com",
  ["icon"]=> string(50) "  "
[2]
  ["name"]=>"City",
  [link]=>"https://www.test.com",
  ["icon"]=> string(50) "  "
```

Basically, after the separator is `","` and it defines how many indexes array will have. In this case, we have three, but for example, we can have only `["name"]=>"America"` and it will have only 1 index.

Appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Please share what output/result you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode first index and then do a loop for creating resultant array:

```
$names = explode(",",$data[0]['name']);    // <-- all names in an array

$res = [];
foreach($names as $name){
    $tmp = [
        "name" => trim($name),
        "link" => $data[0]['link'],
        "icon" => $data[0]['icon'],       
    ];
    $res[] = $tmp;
}

print_r($res);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nUc9f)**